# How to find dimension of a given quotient vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, quotient-spaces

I need to prove the following result from an exercise book.

$V = \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ is a vector space (over $\mathbb{Z_3}$) of all polynomials over $\mathbb{Z_3}$ in indeterminate $x$.

$S = \{x^n + x^{n+2}  : n\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\}$ and $W = \langle S\rangle$.

How to prove that $\dim\left(V/W\right) = 2$ over $\mathbb{Z_3}$.

I know the formula to find the dimension of quotient spaces. But here I am totally unable to prove it. Kindly help to prove the result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You tried guess a basis? (Also note that $x^3=x$)

Comment: $1,x,x^2,x^3+x,x^4+x^2,...,x^{n+2}+x^n,...$ is a basis of $V$, and $S$ is a subset of it.

Comment: What formula are you thinking of using.  Usually formulae are for finite dimensional vector spaces.  This is not the current situation.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yeah, I think you got me. I was thinking in the wrong direction. It is not a finite dimensional space.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Let $P(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. Dividing $P(x)$ by $1+x^2$ you'll get$$P(x)=Q(x)(1+x^2)+a+bx,$$for some $Q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ and some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_3$. But $Q(x)(1+x^2)\in W$.

Comment: Sir, I am unable to understand why we need to divide by $P(x)$?

Comment: Two things: First: I did not divide by $P(x)$; I diveded by $1+x^2$. Second: I did that becase $W$ is precisely the space of those polynomials which are a multiple of $1+x^2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos on question , here after dividing $P(x)$ with $1+x^2$ we get remainder $a+bx$ and this has two parts constant and $x$ so dimension is $2$?

Comment: What has dimension $2$ is $V/W$.

Answer (score 0):

Any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]$ is equivalent mod $W$ to a polynomial of degree $\leq1$.

This is because a term $aX^k$ where $k>1$ is equivalent modulo $\left<S\right>$ to $-aX^{k-2}$, which is equivalent to $aX^{k-4}$, and so on until the degree reaches $0$ or $1$.

Therefore the classes of $1$ and $X$ mod $W$ are a spanning set of $V/W$, and the dimension is at most $2$.

Now to show that the dimension is *equal* to $2$ you need to see why $\{1, X\}$ is a linearly independent family in $V/W$. This is equivalent to $W\cap \operatorname{Span}(\{1, X\})=\{0\}$, and now the reason for which this is true is because every non-zero element of $W$ has degree at least $2$.

Answer (score 0):

The field being $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is irrelevant - the same result holds over any field.  The subspace $W$ contains $1+x^2, x+x^3$, etc.  Modding out by this subspace makes everything in $W$ equal $0$.   So in the quotient vector space $x^2 = -1$, $x^3=-x$, $x^4=-x^2$, etc.  So $\{1,x\}$ is a basis of the quotient space.